# No reconoce plantillas de double - float

Tags: c++, template

Tengo este código en el cual intento aproximar el logaritmo natural de un numero, pero no puedo utilizar ni `if`, `while` o `for`, solo el `if` ternario, pero a la hora que compila me tira errores que `T` es ambiguo y que `elevar` no se ha sobrecargado, pero no entiendo porque. (Solo sirve para numeros entre 0 y 1.

Adjunto mi código:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;

template<class T> T ln1(T x, int n = 10);
template<class T> T ln2(T x, T e = 1e-8);
template<class T> T elevar(T x, T y);

int main() {

    cout << ln1((double)0.5, 500) << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}


template<class T>
T elevar(T x, T y) {
    return (y == 0) ? 1 : x * elevar(x, y - 1);
}

template<class T>
T ln1(T x, int n) {
    return (n == 0) ? 0 : ((elevar(-1, n - 1)*elevar(x - 1, n)) / n) + ln1(x, n - 1);
}
```

PD: Utilizo la conversión para probar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El error que obtengo al compilar tu código es el siguiente:

> ```
> no matching function for call to ‘elevar(double, int&)’
>      return (n == 0) ? 0 : ((elevar(-1, n - 1)*elevar(x - 1, n)) / n) + ln1(x, n - 1);
>                                                ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
> candidate: template<class T> T elevar(T, T)
>  T elevar(T x, T y) {
>    ^~~~~~
> note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
> note:   deduced conflicting types for parameter ‘T’ (‘double’ and ‘int’)
>      return (n == 0) ? 0 : ((elevar(-1, n - 1)*elevar(x - 1, n)) / n) + ln1(x, n - 1);
>                                                ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
> ```

Lo traduciré por si no está claro:

> ```
> no existe ninguna función para llamar a ‘elevar(double, int&)’
>      return (n == 0) ? 0 : ((elevar(-1, n - 1)*elevar(x - 1, n)) / n) + ln1(x, n - 1);
>                                                ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
> la candidata es: template<class T> T elevar(T, T)
>  T elevar(T x, T y) {
>    ^~~~~~
> note:   la deducción/substitución del argumento de plantilla falló:
> note:   se dedujeron tipos diferentes para el parámetro ‘T’ (‘double’ e ‘int’)
>      return (n == 0) ? 0 : ((elevar(-1, n - 1)*elevar(x - 1, n)) / n) + ln1(x, n - 1);
>                                                ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
> ```

Al detalle:

- **No existe ninguna función para llamar a `elevar(double, int&)`**: La función que se ha deducido al instanciar la plantilla es `elevar(double, int&)` pero no existe ninguna función con esa firma. Eso significa que:
- **la deducción/substitución del argumento de plantilla falló**: En el proceso de deducción de tipos, los tipos deducidos para la plantilla no dan lugar a una función válida ya que...
- **Se dedujeron tipos diferentes para el parámetro ‘`T`’ (`double` e `int`)**: Tu plantilla `elevar` tiene un parámetro plantilla (`T`) al instanciarla con `elevar(x - 1, n)` la primera expresión es de tipo `double` (ya que `x` es `double`) y deduce que el primer parámetro debe ser de ese tipo, la segunda expresión es `n` que es de tipo `int` y deduce que el segundo parámetro debe ser de ese tipo... pero según la firma de la plantilla ambos parámetros debían ser el mismo tipo, de ahí el conflicto.

### Soluciones.

#### Más tipos en la plantilla.

Si permites que tu plantilla deduzca tipos distintos, el problema desaparece:

```
template<class T, class U>
//                ~~~~~~~ <--- primer y segundo parámetro no tienen
//                             por qué ser del mismo tipo
T elevar(T x, U y) {
    return (y == 0) ? 1 : x * elevar(x, y - 1);
}
```

#### Explicitar el tipo.

Si dices a la plantilla el tipo con el que trabajará, aunque el segundo parámetro sea de tipo diferente se convertirá (si hay conversión posible):

```
template<class T>
T ln1(T x, int n) {
    return (n == 0) ? 0 : ((elevar<double>(-1, n - 1)*elevar<T>(x - 1, n)) / n) + ln1(x, n - 1);
//                Los dos parámetros serán de tipo 'T' ---> ~~~
}
```

#### Añadir la función al contexto.

Si al sustituir los parámetros se encuentra alguna función que coincide con los parámetros esperados la usará, por ello si añades una función con esa firma en el contexto de uso tu programa compilará:

```
double elevar(double x, int y) {
//            ~~~~~~~~  ~~~~~ <--- No es plantilla, pero tiene la firma esperada
//                                 se usará cuando se deduzca elevar(double, int)
    return (y == 0) ? 1 : x * elevar(x, y - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Si ejecutamos tu programa, obtenemos

> In instantiation of 'T ln1(T, int) [with T = double]':
>   error: no matching function for call to 'elevar(double, int&)'

Lo cual es bastante claro: estás llamando a tu función `elevar( )` con **2 tipos distintos**, cuando tu la has declarado para que use **2 parámetros del mismo tipo**.

Como no se la lógica de las operaciones matemáticas que estás usando, no puedo darte una solución. Pero, tal y como lo tienes, o cambias tus llamadas a `elevar( )` para que usen 2 argumentos del mismo tipo, o cambias la propia función `elevar( )` para que funcione con 2 tipos diferentes.

Answer (score 3):

El error ya te lo está comentando [@Trauma](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/199898/463).

Vamos con las posibles soluciones:

Lo más simple es modificar `elevar` para que el segundo parámetro sea un `int`, ya que es el único uso que le das en tu código:

```
template<class T> T elevar(T x, int y);

// ...

template<class T>
T elevar(T x, int y) {
    return (y == 0) ? 1 : x * elevar(x, y - 1);
}
```

Otra opción pasa por usar dos tipos abstractos diferentes en la función:

```
template<class T, class U> T elevar(T x, U y);

// ...

template<class T, class U>
T elevar(T x, U y) {
    return (y == 0) ? 1 : x * elevar(x, y - 1);
}
```

En la práctica el resultado es exactamente el mismo, pero por sencillez y legibilidad yo aplicaría la primera solución.